# How long do I boil store bought or canned tomato sauce for spaghetti?

Tags: sauce, spaghetti

How long do I boil store bought or canned tomato sauce to use for spaghetti?

I know that tomato sauce can be cooked in cans that are available from the grocery store.  Why should it take 4-6 hours?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice SE. :) Where did you get the idea that it would take 4-6 hours?

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/82160/is-canned-tomato-sauce-already-cooked?rq=1

Comment: I find that you need to cook canned tomato products a bit to remove the "can" flavor present in some canned goods. Simmering for a half hour does it for me, but your taste buds may vary...

Comment: I got this idea that 4-6 hours of simmer on low fire on another website.

Answer (score 7):

If the canned good is already "spaghetti sauce", it simply needs to be heated.  There is no need to cook it for hours.  If you are beginning with canned tomatoes, and making your own sauce, 20 to 30 minutes is usually enough to cook a basic Italian tomato sauce.

Comment: and 'boiling' seems rather extreme, for an operation that would be better described as 'simmering'.